# Grep multiline pattern

Tags: grep, regex, newlines

How do I search for a phrase over multiple lines? E.g. Lets have the phrase "my ice tea" then it may be wrapped in text files:

```
as js skdfh dfh djh sf my
ice tea.
```

grep will not match since there is a newline in between. How do I match those? Another multiline pattern would be `pattern1_\n_pattern2`

I know the easiest way I do ATM is just grep for one part e.g. just ice with -A2 -B2 flag and then in that output againg for e.g. tea. But this is very tedious. So I am interessted on how do you would solve this.

Comment: possible cross site duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could install `pcregrep` (available in most distro repositories) - which is grep using the [pcre library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), which does "Perl Compatible Regular Expressions". It has a command line option `-M` which allows you to do multiline searches - from the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/pcregrep.1.html):

> "The output for any  one match may consist of more than one line."

So you could do

```
pcregrep -M 'my\s+ice\s+tea' filename
```

The `\s` is whitespace, which will match `\n` and `\r` in multiline mode, in addition to the normal whitespace characters. You can also match the newline character directly, so you could do

```
pcregrep -M 'pattern1_\n_pattern2' filename
```

Comment: +1 nice. never heard of it, but tried it and it works like a charm!

Comment: Doesn't `grep -E` do pcre patterns?

Comment: @Daenyth grep -E mostly just means you can use  `?`, `+`, `{`, `|`, `(`, and `)` as their usual regex meaning without having to have a `\ ` in front, as you do if you use standard grep. So `grep 'hello\s\+world' file` is equivalent to `grep -E 'hello\s+world' file`. It doesn't do PCRE. There is `grep -P` for perl regular expressions, but it is experimental (according to the man page) and I think it is a little different from pcregrep ...

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of `-P` when I said `-E`, but I didn't realize it was different.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do a search using `vim`'s `:vimgrep` command.  This works in a manner vaguely similar to that of `grep` but supports vim REs and paths.

Basically you run something like `:vimgrep 'pattern1\npattern2' path/**` for a recursive search, then type `:copen` to bring up a smaller window containing a list of matches.

`vim` REs can do mostly everything that PCREs can, but they evolved separately from the perl regular expression lineage so most of the advanced stuff works differently.  Their basic functionality is more like that of basic REs, but they have some nifty additions that PCREs don't offer.

I'm not sure if it's possible to get `:vimgrep` to spit out data as `grep` does; I've only ever tried to use it for navigation within `vim`.

`:help vimgrep` from within `vim` for more info; `:help pattern.txt` for info on `vim` REs; for more info on paths see `:help wildcards`.

Comment: Be careful -- that's not entirely portable as it will behave differently on different platforms

Comment: @Daenyth: do you mean under the influence of different `.vimrc`'s?  It should be more portable than `grep` with respect to the operating system: `vim` doesn't have a "POSIX flavour", and works more or less identically even under Windows.  ............................................................................. It's possible to add qualifiers to ensure that e.g. the right amount of "magic" gets used on the RE, though as I understand it there is a strict unwritten rule to leave that option the heck alone.

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but apparantly it uses a different backend on windows (`find.exe` instead of `grep`). There was another question within the last few weeks that had that issue.

Comment: @Daenyth: Are you thinking of `:vimgrep` or `:grep`?  From `:help grep`: "The advantage of the internal grep [i.e. `:vimgrep`] is that it works on all systems and uses the powerful Vim search patterns."

Comment: Ah, that must be it. I got the two confused.

Answer (score 3):

Grep only works on one line at a time, but you could use awk to print lines matching a range of patterns:

```
cat file | awk '/foo/,/bar/'
```

it would match anything, not just newlines between the two patterns

Answer (score 0):

To get the most out of unix you need to take advantage of pipes. You can do this in plain `grep` using pipes (no need for tee):

```
$ grep -A1 "pattern1" file.txt |  grep "pattern2"
```

Which I wouldn't consider tedious.

Comment: I think this is error prone, as between pattern1 and pattern2 can exists pattern3 which might not be what your looking for. So you have to control each hit manually.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should work and has the advantage of only using extended regular expressions without the need to install an extra tool like `pcregrep` if you don’t have it yet or don’t have the `-P` option to grep available (eg. macOS):

`egrep -irzo “.*aaa(.*\s.*){1,}.*bbb.*" path_to_filenames`

Caveat emptor: this does some slight disadvantages:

- it will find the largest selection of lines from the first `aaa` to the last `bbb` in each file, unless...
- there are several repetitions of the `aaa` [*stuff*] `bbb` pattern in each file.